# message via ajax is hiding fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem I could not solve

I'm trying to send the message via ajax and update a div when sending the message

the only problem is that when I comment on something that updates a div field textarea and buttons just disappear

I also put a button to display the message field and buttons

Here is the code I'm using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hide_menu(){
    if(document.getElementById('responder').style.display == "none"){

        document.getElementById('responder').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('button').style.display = "block"
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#responder').position().top});        

    }else{
        document.getElementById('responder').style.display = "none"
        document.getElementById('button').style.display = "none"
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#da-content-wrap').position().top});
    }
}
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function($) {
    // Quando o formulário for enviado, essa função é chamada
    $("#da-ex-validate1").submit(function() {
        // Colocamos os valores de cada campo em uma váriavel para facilitar a manipulação
        var mensagem = $("#cleditor").val();
        var user = $("#user").val();
        // Fazemos a requisão ajax com o arquivo envia.php e enviamos os valores de cada campo através do método POST
        $.post('<?= URL::getBase();?>form/insert/comment.php?id=<?=$_id;?>', {user: user, mensagem: mensagem }, function(resposta) {
                // Quando terminada a requisição
                // Exibe a div status
                $("#status").slideDown();
                // Se a resposta é um erro
                if (resposta != false) {
                    // Exibe o erro na div
                    alert('Ocoreu um erro !');
                } 
                // Se resposta for false, ou seja, não ocorreu nenhum erro
                else {
                    $("#mensagens").load('<?= URL::getBase();?>load.php?id=<?= $_id;?>');

                    // Limpando todos os campos
                    $("#cleditor").val('');
                }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the HTML

```
<!-- Content Area -->
<div class="da-panel-content"> <a href="#" onclick="javascript:hide_menu()" id="hidden"><img src="buildings.png" alt=""  />Reply</a>
  <div id="mensagens">
    <?= comments::_build($_id);?>
  </div>
  <form id="da-ex-validate1" class="da-form" method="post" action="javascript:func()" >
    <div id="responder" style="display:none;">
      <textarea id="cleditor" name="mensagem" class="large required"></textarea>
      <input type="hidden" name="user" id="user" value="<? GetInfo::_id(NULL);?>"/>
    </div>
    <div class="da-button-row" id="button" style="display:none;">
      <input type="reset" value="<?= $_LANG[137];?>" class="da-button gray left" />
      <input type="submit" id="da-ex-growl-2" value="<?= $_LANG[219];?>" class="da-button red" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

where is "`<?= comments::_build($_id);?>`" is the list of records.

I also made ​​a page `load.php` practically calls the same function.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V46Nr.jpg

sorry any mistake english :-)

Comment: The flow isn't clear yet. When you click 'responder', the comment box show up? And when you submit, the comment box disappear? Isn't that what you need?

Comment: not exactly a text box appears when you click "reply" when you said something for the first time, she disappears, and click again to "answer" it does not appear, it simply disappears to return to normal have to update the page, but does not want to do that.

Comment: I think you need to check your javascript hide_menu() function     `}else{
            document.getElementById('responder').style.display = "none"`  ,should it really be `"none"`?